# Multiple autocomplete text boxes using same class

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Multiple autocomplete text boxes using same class is not working, is there anyother way to solve it

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.payee_name').autocomplete({
                source:'Billdetails_autocomplete_payee.php', 
                minLength:1,
                select:function(evt,ui)
                {                                   
                     $('input[name="payee_id"]').val(ui.item.vendor_id);
                     $('input[name="default_gl_id"]').val(ui.item.gl_id);                                    
                }
            });                                                                        
         });

    </script>

<input class="payee_name" type="text" name="payee_name" onchange="autoSubmit();">
<input class="payee_name" type="text" name="payee_name" onchange="autoSubmit();">
```

Comment: It should work. What you problem is?

Comment: I don't see in your HTML neither `'input[name="payee_id"]'` nor `'input[name="default_gl_id"]'`